# C++ nlohmann/json how to use runtime provided json_pointers to read json values

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am using the json parser Json for Modern C++ (https://github.com/nlohmann/json). I know that I can get the value of a JSON value with a JSON_Pointer:

`auto v1 = j["/a/b/c"_json_pointer];`

But how would I go about getting the value if the JSON Pointer is defined at runtime (passed into my function)?

```
std:string s1 = "/a/b/c";
auto v1 = j[s1]; // doesn't work
```

You can't append "json_pointer" to either the std::string assignment or to the s1 variable. Is there a function that will convert a std::string to a json_pointer? The caller knows nothing about json and can't have access to the "json.hpp" header. I've also tried

```
std::string s1 = "/a/b/c";
json_pointer p1(s1);
```

but "json_pointer" class is undefined. Other than this issue this is a great library that does everything else I need. TIA.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the source code:

```
inline nlohmann::json::json_pointer operator "" _json_pointer(const char* s, std::size_t)
{
    return nlohmann::json::json_pointer(s);
}
```

If json_pointer is undefined, then you aren't using the right namespaces.  Try

```
using nlohmann::json::json_pointer;
std::string s1 = "/a/b/c";
json_pointer p1(s1);
```

Comment: I swear that was the first thing I tried and wouldn't compile. Just tried again and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the quick and non-judgemental response.

Comment: No problem.  Next time try to build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Half the time when I'm running into an issue, I solve it just by building one in the first place.